# instance method reference. no suitable method found for

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I introducing with new features of java 8.

I have following class:

```
class InstanceMethodClass {

    Integer testStr(String str1,String str2) {
        return str1.compareTo(str2);
    }
}
```

and following invocation:

```
 Arrays.sort(new String[]{"1", "3","2"},InstanceMethodClass::testStr );
```

After it I see following error:

```
java: no suitable method found for sort(java.lang.String[],InstanceMe[...]stStr)
    method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
          cannot find symbol
            symbol:   method testStr(T,T)
            location: class lambdas.staticReferences.InstanceMethodClass))
    method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],int,int,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Please explain what do I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InstanceMethodClass::testStr` has 3 arguments - the two arguments of the method - `String str1,String str2`, and the `InstanceMethodClass` instance for which it is called.

`Arrays.sort` expects a `Comparator<String>`, which requires a method with 2 String arguments.

Your `InstanceMethodClass::testStr` doesn't match. If you change `testStr` to be static, you will get rid of the `InstanceMethodClass` argument, and it should work.

Comment: Is there way to use instance **testStr**  method and method reference?

Comment: @gstackoverflow If Arrays.sort required an argument whose type is a functional interface with a method whose signature is `Integer methodName (InstanceMethodClass a ,String b, String c)`, your instance `testStr` would be a match.

Answer (score 1):

It is working variant:

```
Arrays.sort(new String[]{"1", "3","2"}, new InstanceMethodClass()::testStr );
```